# Heroku Toolbelt - Ruby.exe : no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, command-prompt, heroku-toolbelt

5, 6 months ago, I had, during a few weeks, to release an application under Heroku. So, I downloaded, installed Heroku Toolbelt and released my application: I didn't have problems.

This morning, I started doing this application again and when I wanted to log in to Heroku with the command `heroku login`, I had exactly the following error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby-1.9.2\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- heroku (LoadError)`.

First, I reinstalled Heroku Toolbelt, but I still had the same problem, then I downloaded the zipped Heroku Toolbelt from Github, without success. So, I began looking on Google for a solution to this problem.

I put ruby-1.9.2 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin\ and changed the Ruby path in the heroku.bat file. I took advantage of it to put some 'PAUSE' in heroku.bat, to understand what is taking place, but found nothing of abnormal. In brief, I work on for 10 in the morning (French time) and absolutely found nothing.

This is why I came there to ask this question on Stackoverflow (one of the best forums for me). I hope somebody understood me and can help me. Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I think you are having is that you moved the installation of Ruby from the top-level **`C:\`** directory to an uncommon place where it will not be found by the system. When you install Ruby on Windows, it is advisable to have it in a place where it can always be accessed, whether you have administrative rights or not and in a folder that does not have any spaces or special characters in the name. When Ruby is installed correctly, it creates a folder called **`Ruby193`** in my top-level directory: **`C:\Ruby193`**. In addition, your system **`Paths`** are modified through **`Windows Environment Variables`** and this is added to your path: **`C:\Ruby193\bin;`**. This allows you to run **`ruby`** followed by any command from any location through the command-line on the system. All that is left to do is install the heroku-toolbelt and things should be running smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @KareyPowell's answer, this problem for me was caused by having updated Ruby, and was fixed by updating a line in the heroku script (found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin\heroku`) to point at my updated version of Ruby.

I changed it from:

```
bindir=`cd -P "${0%/*}/../ruby-1.9.2/bin" 2>/dev/null; pwd`
```

to:

```
bindir=`cd -P "/c/Ruby193/bin" 2>/dev/null; pwd`
```

I should say that I'm not totally clear what that `${0%/*}` bit does (would be interested to know, if anyone can tell me), so it's possible my change could introduce problems, but it certainly seems to work.